# What was the first true inflatable space habitat : BEAM, Genesis I, Genesis II or none?

Tags: space-station, habitat, bigelow, expandable, bigelow-expandable-module

I'd wager BEAM (2016) is the first true inflatable space habitat because it was specifically designed for human habitation, and as such attached to the ISS, whereas Genesis I (2006) and Genesis II (2007) were technology demonstration prototypes.
But honestly I don't know what this argument is worth.

And frankly one could argue none of them are true space habitats, yet great steps on the way to a mature version of the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Not a habitat as such, but the first inflatable human-rated facility if you like was on Voskhod 2, equipped with an inflatable airlock.

Otherwise, as able to sustain human life as a berthed module of the ISS,  BEAM is indeed the first inflatable habitat.

Everything else is as you say.

> The BEAM module was developed by Bigelow Aerospace and installed on the ISS as the **first
> ever human occupied inflatable module**.

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190001443/downloads/20190001443.pdf

Other links:

First Inflatable Habitat for Astronauts All Pumped On Space Station

https://science-atlas.com/human-spaceflights/first-inflatable-habitat-for-astronauts-all-pumped-on-space-station/

1st Inflatable Habitat for Astronauts All Pumped Up on Space Station

https://www.space.com/32992-beam-inflatable-space-habitat-success.html

An astronaut just deployed the Space Station's first inflatable habitat

https://mashable.com/article/international-space-station-inflatable-room

Astronauts enter world's first inflatable space habitat (Update)

https://phys.org/news/2016-06-astronauts-world-inflatable-space-lodge.html

First Ever Inflatable Habitat Attached To The International Space Station

https://www.iflscience.com/first-ever-inflatable-habitat-attached-international-space-station-35134

sub-scale inflatable space module test:

https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/boom-watch-an-inflatable-space-habitat-explode-during-testing-video/ar-AA1dG2kR

https://spaceref.com/newspace-and-tech/lockheed-martin-inflatable-habitat-subscale-burst-test/

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Voskhod 2